# How to fulfill a string condition?

Tags: java

```
String Enterproducts=in.next();

for(int i=0;i<?;i++)
```

I want to keep entering products until they are finished. What should be here? Can we use 
`.compareto()` method? if yes then how?

Comment: What is `in` in your example?

Comment: Are you saying you want to keep looping until the user wants to stop inputting string values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should using while loop like:

```
while (in.hasNext()) {
    Enterproducts=in.next();
    if (Enterproducts.equals ("end")) {
        break;
    }
    //apply your business logic here what you want to do with entered string.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
do {
    Enterproducts = in.next();
} while (!Enterproducts.equalsIgnoreCase("end"));
```

Answer (score 0):

or try this one:

```
for (int i = 0; in.hasNext()&& !Enterproducts.equals ("quit"); i++) {
      Enterproducts=in.next();
}
```